# Wordpress 4.1 crashes loading of ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: javascript

**Edit: to keep things organized:**

- This one IS working (WordPress 4.0.1): https://topografieindeklas.nl/topotrainer/provincies/
- This one IS NOT working (WordPress 4.1): https://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/provincies/

Conclusion, so far: something differs between WordPress 4.0.1 and 4.1 that makes it impossible for DoJo (living inside the ArcGIS Javascript API) to declare the `require` statement

I'm running a Wordpress [website](https://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/provincies/) which uses both jQuery and DoJo (part of the ArcGIS JS API, loaded from http://js.arcgis.com/3/12/). 
After recently upgrading from Wordpress 4.0.1 to 4.1, things broke.
Dojo is returning multiple Error: multipleDefine errors.

Basically it looks like DoJo tries to load a new instance of jQuery, which it shouldn't, since WordPress has loaded jQuery already and there isn't a jQuery module available in the DoJo map. Furthermore, this issues seems to only exists in WordPress, not in a jsfiddle I made including exactly the same scripts.

For debugging purposes I first disabled all WordPress plugins, without any result; the problem kept existing. I went on and found a couple of interesting things. But I'm really stuck in the further debugging proccess. I know the scope of this question is rather broad, but any thoughts at all are very much appreciated.

*What I know so far/that i'm wondering about:*

-Things stopped working after upgrading to WordPress 4.1

-In the info of the multipleDefine error it states https://js.arcgis.com/3.11/jquery.js, which is weird: it shouldn't be looking for jQuery there, since it's already included in Wordpress

-Things break as soon as I included the ArcGIS Javascript API, which includes DoJO, but only in WordPress; on a jsfiddle things work fine http://jsfiddle.net/dhunink/mry5vn3s/7/

```
<script>
  var dojoConfig = { 
    isDebug: true,
    async: false
  };
</script>

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/"></script>
```

[image][image]
The things mentioned above leads me to the conclusion that something changed in the last WordPress release that effects my script, although I can't find anything in the release notes that could be linked to my issue.

Any thoughts, suggestions or comments are highly appreciated! Feel free to see all in action at https://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/provincies/.

EDIT:
The issues occurs both when the API is hardcoded in via  tag's, as per the wp_register_script/wp_enqueue_script.
Although wp_register_script is absolutely favorable, I have been able to use the code below in the past, based on a WordPress shot code [get_provincie_minimap]:

```
add_shortcode( 'get_provincie_minimap', 'construct_provincie_minimap' );
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'get_provincie_minimap_include_css' );
function get_provincie_minimap_include_css() {
    global $post;
    $arcGISAPIoptions = get_option( 'tpgrf_theme_arcGISAPI_options' ); $arcGISAPIversion = $arcGISAPIoptions['arcGISAPI_versionnumber'];

    if ( strstr( $post->post_content, '[get_provincie_minimap' ) ) {// Check if shortcode exists in page or post content
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/'.$arcGISAPIversion.'/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>';
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//js.arcgis.com/'.$arcGISAPIversion.'/esri/css/esri.css" />';
    }
}

function construct_provincie_minimap($args){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'fire' => 'no',
    ), $args));

    global $post; 
    $children = get_pages(array(
                        'title_li'=> '',
                        'child_of' => $post->ID,
                        'parent' => $post->ID,
                        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                        'post_status' => 'publish'
                    ));
    foreach($children as $child){
        $options .= '<option value="'.get_page_link( $child->ID ).'">'.$child->post_title.'</option>';
    }

    $arcGISAPIoptions = get_option( 'tpgrf_theme_arcGISAPI_options' ); $arcGISAPIversion = $arcGISAPIoptions['arcGISAPI_versionnumber'];

    $output = '
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//js.arcgis.com/'.$arcGISAPIversion.'/"></script>
        <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $("#selectProvinceListShortcode").on("change", function(){
              if($(this).val()){
                window.location.href = $(this).val();
              }
            });
        });

            require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/graphic", "esri/tasks/query", "esri/dijit/InfoWindow", "esri/config", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/on", "dojo/mouse", "dojo/domReady!"], 
            function(
                map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, FeatureLayer, Graphic, query, infoWindow, esriConfig, BorderContainer, ContentPane, on, mouse, dom
            ){

            var basemapURL          = "'.$serverProtocol.'//tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_nederland_ondergrond/MapServer";
            map = new esri.Map("mapSelectProvince",{
                zoom:7,
                center: [5.12, 52.30]
            });  

            var contentFeatureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("'.$serverProtocol.'//services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_nederland/FeatureServer/0",{
                mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.ON_DEMAND,
                outFields: ["*"],
                infoWindow: infoWindow
            });
            contentFeatureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("Type=\'Provincie\'");

            map.addLayer(new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(basemapURL));
            map.addLayer(contentFeatureLayer);

            contentFeatureLayer.on("mouse-over", function(evt){
                var name = evt.graphic.attributes.NAME;
                if(name == "Fryslân (Friesland)"){
                    name = "Friesland";
                }
                if(name == "Groningen (prov.)"){
                    name = "Groningen";
                }
                if(name == "Utrecht (prov.)"){
                    name = "Utrecht";
                }
                map.setMapCursor("pointer");
                map.infoWindow.setTitle(evt.graphic.attributes.NAME);
                map.infoWindow.setContent(\'Provincie <a href="'.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/topotrainer/provincies/\'+name+\'/">\'+evt.graphic.attributes.NAME+\' oefenen</a>\');
                map.infoWindow.show(evt.graphic.geometry);
            })

            contentFeatureLayer.on("mouse-out", function(evt){
                map.setMapCursor("default");
            })

            contentFeatureLayer.on("click", function(evt){
                var name = evt.graphic.attributes.NAME;
                if(name == "Fryslân (Friesland)"){
                    name = "Friesland";
                }
                if(name == "Groningen (prov.)"){
                    name = "Groningen";
                }
                if(name == "Utrecht (prov.)"){
                    name = "Utrecht";
                }
                window.location = \''.get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/topotrainer/provinces/\'+name+\'/\';
            });

        });//End require
    </script>
    <p>Of kies uit de lijst: <select id="selectProvinceListShortcode" name="selectProvinceListShortcode" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select"><option value="">selecteer...</option>'.$options.'</select></p>
    <div id="mainMapWindow" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:\'headline\', gutters:false">
        <div id="mapSelectProvince" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:\'center\'"></div>
    </div>
    ';//End output
    return $output;
};
```

Comment: How do you add the script? Please show your code + the hook it's running on. Take a look at your theme as well. Try it not only without plugins, but with one of the default themes.

Comment: Hi Kaiser. Thanks for the comment!
Unfortunately the issue occurs no matter which method I use, wether it's the official wp_enqueue_script method or just hardcode it in <script> tags inline html.

Comment: You want to use the _Dependencies API_ (`wp_enqueue_script()`, etc.) anyway. Just [edit] your question and show the code you are currently using. In the best case, you quickly build a simple (mu-)plugin so we have something to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @kaiser thanks for the quick response! You'r absolutely right, the dependencies api would be the right way. However, I've been able to do it a bit different (until the 4.1 update). Altered my post to show the code I have been using. Any further responses are very very appreciated. I'm really stuck....

Comment: this is very unlikely to have anything to do with the wordpress upgrade. In any case the first step is to understand why do you have the script errors and the best place for it is the support of the library that you use. (The 404 on jquery might have been there before and you havn't noticed because you didn't had any reason to look for errors?)

Comment: Agree with @MarkKaplun. I've been looking your web and it seems that the problem has nothing to do with the WordPress upgrade. And, for your information, the `Error: multipleDefine` is triggered in `http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/` (lines 15, 41 and 42) not in `https://js.arcgis.com/3.11/jquery.js` as you said. You should investigate what that error in `http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/` means, which you should ask to the their support service.

Comment: Hi Guys! I did thought of a failure in the ArcGIS Javascript API at first (which is build with DoJo). After lot's of research I found out that the DoJo multipleDefine error is likely to be fired when there's a conflict with jQuery (see for example https://geonet.esri.com/thread/118960).
So I checked my test-server, which was running WordPress 4.0.1. Changed nothing and upgraded to 4.1. After that upgrade the error started to occur. So that lead me to the idea something changed in Wordpress (loading jQuery) that affects the ArcGIS Javascript API....

Comment: ust got a backup running on topografieindeklas.nl/restore/topotrainer/provincies . This one is running WordPress 4.0.1. and works like a charm...
For comparison: this one runs 4.1 and fails: https://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/provincies/

Comment: hello dear Dennis , hello dear Mark good day dear Kaiser, - many thanks for the great thread: 

can i include this map in Wordpress: 
map: https://npgeo-corona-npgeo-de.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/348b643c8b234cdc8b1b345210975b87_0
data: https://npgeo-corona-npgeo-de.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/348b643c8b234cdc8b1b345210975b87_0/data

note: i want to have both - the data and the map!?